# How to change ticks fontsize of a plot using PyQtgraph

Tags: python, plot, font-size, pyqtgraph

everything is in the title, how to change the fontsize of the ticks using pyqtgraph ?

Thx

Comment: everything is probably in the doc. Maybe as your code ? and your trials ?

Comment: Everything is in google! In how far does this not help? Please make sure you have [taken the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and especially have read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for being not precise enough. The documentation of pyqtgraph didn't help me and google neither. 
I saw a post on the pyqtgraph support forum that indicates to use the setStyle function with the keyword 'tickFont' but I can not figure out how to use it properly.
So if create my graph with self.my_plot = pg.PlotWidget() and then use self.my_plot.setStyle(xxx), what I should put instead of xxx to have for example a fontsize twice bigger compared to the original one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way to change the font size of the ticklabels in pyqtgraph is to first create a new font within PyQt and set the fontsize to it. Then this font can be applied to the ticks.

```
font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(20)
plot.getAxis("bottom").tickFont = font
```

Initially I would have thought that something like
`plot.getAxis("bottom").setStyle(tickFont = font)`
should work as well, but for some reason it doesn't.

Once the font size has increased, it may make sense to adapt the tickOffset as well. Find a complete running code is below.

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 1000)
y = np.sin(x) / x

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
plot = win.addPlot(x=x, y=y, title="Plot")
plot.setLabel('bottom', "some x axis label")

font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(20)
plot.getAxis("bottom").tickFont = font
plot.getAxis("bottom").setStyle(tickTextOffset = 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For Pyqtgraph 0.11 the syntax has changed to:

```
font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(20)
plot.getAxis("bottom").setStyle(tickFont = font)
```

or

```
plot.getAxis("bottom").setTickFont(font)
```

Comment: Savior! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's not much documentation on this it seems like, but anybody else that was struggling with this like I did might find the [source code for AxisItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/AxisItem.html#AxisItem) useful.